# Update Gradle2.2.2 bug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After I updated Gradle to 2.2.2 version, have the next bug :

```
Error:(159, 1) A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Could not get unknown property 'processReleaseQAGoogleServices' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

But in gradle tasks there is such task and it works.
The bug is in `afterEvaluate`

In the next file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

android {
signingConfigs {
    debug {//...}
    releaseQA {//...}
    release {//...}
    debugProduction {//...}
    amazonQA {//...}
    amazonRelease {//...}
}

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "*"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode "code"
    versionName "name"
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
buildTypes {
    debug {//...}
    releaseQA  {//...}
    release {//...}
    debugProduction  {//...}
    amazonQA {//...}
    {//...}
}
}

def appModuleRootFolder = '.'
def srcDir = 'src'
def googleServicesJson = 'google-services.json'

task switchToDebug(type: Copy) {
def buildType = 'debug'
description = 'Switches to DEBUG google-services.json'
from "${srcDir}/${buildType}"
include "$googleServicesJson"
into "$appModuleRootFolder"}

task switchToRelease(type: Copy) {
def buildType = 'release'
description = 'Switches to RELEASE google-services.json'
from "${srcDir}/${buildType}/"
include "$googleServicesJson"
into "$appModuleRootFolder"}

afterEvaluate {
processDebugGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToDebug
processReleaseQAGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToDebug
processReleaseGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToRelease
processDebugProductionGoogleServices.dependsOn switchToRelease}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'io.socket:socket.io-client:0.6.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"` & `targetSdkVersion 24`

Comment: not work @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Okay .Did you solve yet ?